# Why could a Java Swing program not display German characters such as umlauts (ä, ö, ...)?

Tags: java, swing, gradle

The Swing program shows wrong characters instead of German umlauts. This button should be "Schließen", for example: [image]. This occurs for all UI elements as far as I can see.

The code to create the UI is nothing unusual, for example:

```
about = new JButton("");
about.setToolTipText("Über das Programm");
```

I already checked following things:

1. The encoding of the .java files is utf-8 (checked with VS code)
2. The font is javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=Dialog,name=Dialog,style=bold,size=12]. Dialog appears to be the default font, so it would be strange if it did not support umlauts. But I have not found a way to check this, because when I check my installed fonts through windows I don't find a font called "Dialog".

The project also uses gradle (6.8).

What could be a reason for this behaviour? When I talked to somebody who compiled the same program on Linux they didn't seem to have this problem.

Edit:

I also found code such as this:

```
JLabel test = new JLabel();
test.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
test.setText("<html>Something with ß</html>");
```

Arial surely supports umlauts, but this code still did not display the ß correctly

Comment: It seems that the java compiler isn't aware of the utf8 encoding of your source files. Is utf8 your system encoding? If not: do you compile with `javac -encoding utf8`?

Comment: @ThomasKläger It seems to be my system encoding: >>> import sys
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'utf-8'

Comment: Not necessarily. On my machine the system default encoding (on Windows by executing `CHCP` from the command line) is Windows codepage 850 (DOS Latin 1), but in Python `sys.getdefaultencoding()` still returns "utf-8". On a linux machine you code execute `locale charmap` to find the system encoding.

Comment: @ThomasKläger You are right, mine was also codepage 850. Thanks to your general suggestion I managed to solve the problem by editing my build.gradle (like I write in the answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Parse source code as UTF-8

Thanks to the commenters I could get to the bottom of the issue: The compiler was not parsing my source code as UTF-8 character encoding.

I had to add following to my `build.gradle` file:

```
compileJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```